# React-native search bar - error: undefined is not a function (near '... this.state.books.filter...')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, searchbar

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I added a searchbar but when I write something in the textfield it gives me the error: "undefined is not a function (near '... this.state.books.filter...')"

Below is some of my  code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 state = {
    books: {},
};
componentDidMount() {
        firebase
        .database()
        .ref('/Books')
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({ books: snapshot.val() });
        });
}
searchBooks = value => {
    const { books } = this.state;
    const bookArray = Object.values(books);
    const filteredBooks = bookArray.filter(book => {
        let bookLowercase = (book.bookname).toLowerCase();
        let searchTermLowercase = value.toLowerCase();
        return bookLowercase.indexOf(searchTermLowercase) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({ books: filteredBooks });
};

render() {
    const { books } = this.state;
    if (!books) {
        return null;
    }
    const bookArray = Object.values(books);
    const bookKeys = Object.keys(books);
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            {/*Searchbar */}
            <View style={{ height: 80, backgroundColor: '#c45653', justifyContent: "center", paddingHorizontal: 5 }}>
                <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white', flexDirection: 'row', padding: 5, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{
                            fontSize: 24,
                            marginLeft: 15
                        }}
                        placeholder="Search"
                        onChangeText={value => this.searchBooks(value)}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>

            <FlatList
                style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.searchBarFocused ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' : 'white' }}
                data={bookArray}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => bookKeys[index]}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <BookListItem
                        book={item}
                        id={bookKeys[index]}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelectBook}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing `this.state.books` as an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```
state = {
    books: {},
};
```

Objects have no filter function. You probably want to use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead.

```
state = {
    books: [],
};
```

Then you'll be able to use `this.state.books.filter()` with the Array's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Comment: Thanks. So I edited my code above in the searchbooks method. Now it works but the list is saved and the whole list is not coming back. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Martin it'd probably be better to create a new question with the updated code. However, on your current render function, you need to remove and replace the occurrences of `Object.values` and `Object.keys` as your dealing with an Array instead of an Object.